# Chrome extension upgrade leaving extension without javascript files

Tags: google-chrome-extension, upgrade, chrome-web-store

I have an extension in the Chrome Webstore with ~400 000 users. Since a couple of months ago I have been getting e-mails from users whose extension has stopped working for them. They're basically just seeing the HTML page in the popup and options page. No content dynamically added by any JavaScript. After some helpful debugging from one user it appeared that the JavaScript files were gone. He sent me the following screenshot:

[image]

So what appears to happen is that the JS files become unreachable, or disappear. My guess is that this happen when an upgrade occurs. I haven't moved or changed the names of any files in any recent updates. No big changes have occurred at all.

I have solved this by sending instructions on how to find the extension on the hard drive, and attaching the extension files, so they manually themselves have to patch the extension. This always works. Now today, after receiving 4 e-mails within an hour with the same problem, I've had enough.

One user had all her extensions stop working at the same time. My guess being that this problem was the culprit. Me sending the patch to her solved the issue for my extension at least.

So my question to stackoverflow is: Has anyone else experienced this? This seems like quite a serious issue with Chrome. It started appearing around Chrome 20 and still happens with 22. My manifest version was prior to a couple of days ago 1.

The extension in question: http://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pnjaodmkngahhkoihejjehlcdlnohgmp?hl=en.

Comment: A quick look shows that the iframes in the options page do not run in the extension's context. Don't have the time to look further, but just pointing this out so that you can debug yourself.

Comment: Which version of Chrome are you using? The iframes are working in Chrome 22, and iframes not running in the context of the extension was a bug we saw in Chrome 21.

Comment: That error was observed in Chrome 21 indeed. The extension seems to work in Chrome 22 (blank profile with default settings).

Comment: I have pushed a workaround for the iframe issue in Chrome 21, so that's not the issue any more.

Comment: Do you happen to use the omnibox attribute in your manifest? We are experiencing the same exact thing with a small (but growing) portion of our user base and we are also at a loss for HOW this situation came about.

Comment: No, I'm not. Which manifest version are you using? Ever since I switched to manifest version 2 there have been less of these errors.